# Why memmap IO are ignored in /proc/[PID]/io

Tags: memory, io, proc

I have a problem /proc/[PID]/io and memmap
I need to profile application IO that uses python library [astropy](http://docs.astropy.org).
One of the problem I have is that IO read/write total bytes are incorrect in /proc/[PID]/io.

I have a script `copy.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
cp huge.fits huge.2.fits
#python copyfits.py
#python copyfitsMemmapOFF.py
sleep 5 
cat /proc/$$/io
```

I comment the `cp` line to and the line I want to run for each test.

`copyfits.py` contains:

```
from astropy.io import fits    
hdulist = fits.open('huge.fits', mode='readonly')
hdulist.writeto('huge.2.fits')
hdulist.close()
```

`copyfitsMemmapOFF.py` contains:

```
    from astropy.io import fits    
    hdulist = fits.open('huge.fits', mode='readonly', memmap=False)
    hdulist.writeto('huge.2.fits')
    hdulist.close()
```

heres the IO results for each solution:

`cp huge.fits huge.2.fits`

```
rchar: 9749929202
wchar: 9749551680
```

`python copyfits.py`

```
**rchar: 8399421**
wchar: 9749551685
```

`python copyfitsMemmapOFF.py`

```
rchar: 9757502959
wchar: 9749551685
```

I understand that memmap being off will lead to inconsistent IO results when using this variable to monitor how much the application read files. 
How/Why memmap are not counted in standard IO, and how can I found out about those IO ?
Because if it's kernel instead of application reading file, the file is still accessed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/proc`’s `io` only tracks “explicit” I/O, *i.e.* I/O performed using a small number of system calls. For reads, those are `read`, `readv`, `preadv`, `sendfile`, and `copy_file_range`; you can see the stats accumulated using [`add_rchar`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/add_rchar) in [`fs/read_write.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/read_write.c).

I/O for memory-mapped files is quite different; when reading, it relies on page-fault handling, with a number of optimisations to increase performance (read-ahead etc.) You can track that to some extent by looking at page faults in `/proc/${pid}/stat` (fields 10 and 12). The hard part is figuring out how much data is read with each page fault; my experiments suggest 64KiB per fault but I haven’t found hard data to back that up (and it probably depends on circumstances).

I don’t know of any ready-to-use way of tracing mapped I/O from the point of view of the process (*i.e.* bytes read into the process, regardless of whether any block I/O actually occurred).

Accounting for memory-mapped reads accurately turns out to be quite a tough problem, mainly because of the way accounting has to reflect intention. `io` counts bytes which a program explicitly asked to read or write; but when a process maps a file into its memory, reads occur with a granularity determined by the kernel, not the reading process. You could read only one byte every 4KiB, and the kernel will read in the entire file for you — what should the accounting reflect? It can’t easily reflect bytes really read in memory by the process, that would have a huge performance impact (on top of being impossible to implement across all architectures).